# Change Jquery UI Draggable revert based on the positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, draggable

I have a container that is draggable and want 4 revert positions:

1. top left corner
2. top right corner
3. bottom left corner
4. bottom right corner

When I'm dragging the container over 50% over the *top left* position in automatically should slide to the *top right* position and so one for every other corner.

I am relative new to this and just got figured out how to revert to only one position.

I am glad for any help. Thank you :)

**JqueryUI for now:**

```
$("#draggable").draggable({
  revert: 'invalid',
  containment: 'body',
});
```

**Fiddle for now:** (borders are only to help what I mean with the positioning)
http://jsfiddle.net/wSLJC/125/

Comment: Something is throwing off the positioning, but here is a start: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/wSLJC/128/

Comment: Nice. Thank you. Will keep it a try :)